# What is the difference between using django signals and calling a method?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, signals

I am trying to implement a function which sends a notification to all employee records whenever a new document record is published. In the models, I still needed to import the receiver function because my sender model lives in a different project:

receiver function (lives in a different app in project):

```
def new_document_version_published(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    print("New version of document published!")
    print(sender)
    print(instance)

    # Get all employees
    employees = []

    # Send notifications to employees
    buttons = [NotificationButton(button_text="New version of document", value="Ok", style="primary")]
    notifyUsers("A new version of the document has been published", buttons, employees, [])
```

sender (lives in a different app in project):

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from api.views import new_document_version_published

    class DocumentVersion:
        ...
        def save(self, *args, **kw):
            if self.pk is not None:
                orig = DocumentVersion.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
                if orig.date_published != self.date_published:
                    print('date_published changed')
                    notify_employees()
                if orig.date_approved != self.date_approved:
                    print('date_approved changed')
            super(DocumentVersion, self).save(*args, **kw)
    
    def notify_employees():
        post_save.connect(new_document_version_published, sender=DocumentVersion)
```

I know there is something wrong with my implementation because I don't understand what is the difference between using the signal and just importing and calling the receiver function. All help appreciated!

Comment: signal are use for case like in the document `helps decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework`. Sure you can just import the receiver function everytime the action is called, or you only need to write 1 time with signal

Answer (score 1):

## What is the difference

**Calling a function** makes the caller dependent on (or at least aware of) the receiver function, while **using Django signals** makes the receiver function dependent on the signal being called by its caller(s).

From https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/signals/:

> ... helps decoupled applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a set of receivers that some action has taken place. They’re especially useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.

### When to use Django signals

From https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/signals.html:

> Signals have a variety of problems and unforeseen consequences.
> ...

> Often it is better to avoid using signals. One can implement a lot of logic *without* signals.
> ...

> Signals can still be a good solution if you want to handle events raised by a *third party* Django application.
> ...

## What that difference looks like

### Calling a function

Pre-save:

```py
# notify_employees()                                  # Replace this
new_document_version_published(self.__class__, self)  # with this
```

Post-save:

```py
class DocumentVersion(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        orig = None  # .........  # Add this
        if self.pk is not None:
            orig = DocumentVersion.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if orig.date_published != self.date_published:
                print('date_published changed')
                # notify_employees()                              # Replace this
            if orig.date_approved != self.date_approved:
                print('date_approved changed')

        super(DocumentVersion, self).save(*args, **kw)

        if orig and orig.date_published != self.date_published:   # with this
            new_document_version_published(self.__class__, self)  #
```

### Using Django Signals

Since Django's `post_save` signal doesn't pass `orig`, let's use a custom signal:

1. Define a signal.
2. Send the signal.
3. Implement the receiver function.
4. Connect the receiver function, usually where the receiver function is defined.

Post-save:

```py
post_save_published = Signal()  # Add this


class DocumentVersion(models.Model):
    ...
    def save(self, *args, **kw):
        orig = None  # .........  # Add this
        if self.pk is not None:
            orig = DocumentVersion.objects.get(pk=self.pk)
            if orig.date_published != self.date_published:
                print('date_published changed')
                # notify_employees()                                        # Replace this
            if orig.date_approved != self.date_approved:
                print('date_approved changed')

        super(DocumentVersion, self).save(*args, **kw)

        if orig and orig.date_published != self.date_published:             # with this
            post_save_published.send(sender=self.__class__, instance=self)  #
```

```py
def new_document_version_published(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    # ...


post_save_published.connect(new_document_version_published, sender=DocumentVersion)  # Add this
```